# Issues with Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following in my .htaccess file:

**Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"**

It works perfectly! But it is bad security practise.

When I change it to:

**Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "http://example.com"**

I get the following error:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://example.com/oc/catalog/view/javascript/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.4.0. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' does not match 'http://example.com').

How do I handle this?

Comment: The error message doesn't say that. If it did then you'd been generating a cross origin error for a request to the *same origin*. It looks like you've sanitised the URL by replacing every host name with `example.com` and, in the process, hidden the problem.

Comment: I haven't made any changes to the url, except that I changed the website name to example. If you want me to list the unedited info, please let me know. Please note, I get this error when accessing the website through www.example.com instead of example.com

Comment: Yes, list the unedited info. At the moment the question claims you are making a request from `http://example.com/` to `http://example.com/` and it is blocked because it isn't from `http://example.com/`.

Comment: I am accessing the website **www**.arvindint.com/oc. In the htaccess, I have entered - `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "http://arvindint.com"`. The error I get is - _`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at arvindint.com/oc/catalog/view/javascript/font-awesome/fonts/‌​…. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' does not match 'arvindint.com').`_ Stackoverflow seems to be removing the "http://" before the links in the comments.

Comment: The actual error message you get (in Chrome) is: `Font from origin 'http://arvindint.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://arvindint.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://www.arvindint.com' is therefore not allowed access.` As my answer says, `http://arvindint.com` is not the same as `http://www.arvindint.com`. One has an extra `www.` in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the live site:

> `Font from origin 'http://arvindint.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://arvindint.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://www.arvindint.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

From a comment from the OP:

> Please note, I get this error when accessing the website through www.example.com instead of example.com

That is your problem.

If you give permission to `example.com` but not to `www.example.com` then you can't access it from `www.example.com`.

Permissions are on a per-origin basis, not on a per-second-level-domain basis.

Pick one of the two host names (with or without `www`) and stick to it. Redirect from one to the other. Don't host your site on two different host names. Doing so is more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: Thank you for your advice on redirection. However, if I want the above situation to work should I also add - `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "http://www.example.com"` to the htaccess file?

Comment: No. You can only provide one value. If you aren't using a wild card and need to support multiple origins then you have to generate it dynamically. You can't use a static value if you don't want the universal *.